# React context API when wrapped around index.js file it's display nothing

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am learning about context API and creating an add basket functionality in the Context.js file I have created a context that which will I use for my application it's code is

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";

const Cart = createContext();

function Context({ childern }) {
  return <Cart.Provider>{childern}</Cart.Provider>;
}

export default Context;
```

now I am wrapping my App component around it in the index.js file

```
import Context from "./context/Context";

<Context>
      <App />
    </Context>
```

but after doing this on the browser it display nothing no error not a single component that I have created is displayed but when I unwrapped the  component it works fine

Comment: Spell `children` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Context({ props }) {
  return <Cart.Provider>{props.childern}</Cart.Provider>;
}
```

Now it will work. Just add "props" in props and "props.children" in provider.